# How to open quickly – in a browser – a Wikipedia URL from Dictionary or from the 'Look Up in Dictionary' service dialogue?

Tags: services, web-browser

### Example

Either:

- in **Dictionary**, I am at the Wikipedia page for something; or
- in a Services-capable web browser such as Safari I select a phrase, then use the contextual menu to **Look Up "…"** (and that thing is found in Wikipedia).

#### Aim

Open the Wikipedia URL in the web browser. Ideally in a new tab or new window.

In the past, I could do so quickly – without multiple steps.

In Mountain Lion now, I can't do so. I doubt that the feature/routine is lost … more likely forgotten by me (I have used Mountain Lion for a few months, but I can't recall when I last used the Wikipedia routine outlined above).

## Question

How can I open quickly – **in a web browser** – a Wikipedia URL from **Dictionary** or from the **Look Up "…"** dialogue?

Answer (score 1):

In Dictionary.app at the foot of the page there's an option:

- View web page.

This is **not** the routine that I recall.

Also the URL is **not** what's required – example: I want http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit but Dictionary links to http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Parity_bit …